# Programmatically navigate PowerPoint

Tags: macos, powerpoint

I have PowerPoint 2008 running on my Mac. Is there a way to navigate, like forward and backward, the PowerPoint presentation using some program in Python, Java, C/C++ or other language?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing this? You can create slideshow's that run with timers and activate events and such. Is that what you are getting at?

Comment: Ultimately, I'm implementing a remote app on iPhone, which can remotely control Powerpoint. Now my app can send command to a server on my Mac. And I want to use the received command to control the running Powerpoint, namely, navigate.

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Applescript. If you can't script Powerpoint directly (look in its script Library using the editor) you can send keypresses to it using the accessibility framework.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript. There are some examples here: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.03/23.03AppleScriptPowerPoint/index.html. Unfortunately, all of the Mac Office 2008 VBA to AppleScript samples have been removed permanently from Microsoft's site.